# What can be wrong in redirection

Tags: c, linux, io-redirection

Here is my C code, it works fine, I am trying to make it work with IO redirection and fail, can't understand what's the reason of error here, I made test file test1.in and I am waiting to get output in test1.out but test1.out is empty after the run
`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 80


/*******************************************************/
int my_strcmp(char[], char[]);
int my_strncmp(char[], char[], unsigned int);
int my_strchr(char[], int);
/*******************************************************/

int main(){
    
    int test = 0, running = 1;
    
    char str1[MAX_STR_SIZE];
    char str2[MAX_STR_SIZE];
    
    char c;
    int count;
    
    printf("\nLet's start testing!");
    
    while(running){
        
        printf("\n Enter 1: to test my_strcmp(), 2: to test my_strncmp(), 3: to test my_strchr()");
        scanf("%d",&test);
    
        switch(test){
            case 1:     /*my_strcmp test*/
            
                printf("\n***my_strcmp*** TEST");
                
                printf("\nEnter first string: ");
                scanf("%s",str1);
                
                printf("Enter second string: ");
                scanf("%s",str2);
                
                printf("\nThe result is: %d\n",my_strcmp(str1, str2));
                break;  
                
                    
            case 2:         /*my_strncmp test*/
            
                printf("\n***my_strncmp*** TEST");
                
                printf("\nEnter first string: ");
                scanf("%s",str1);
                
                printf("Enter second string: ");
                scanf("%s",str2);
                
                printf("Enter maximal number of bytes to compare: ");
                scanf("%d",&count);
                
                printf("\nThe result is: %d\n",my_strncmp(str1, str2, count));
                break;
                
            case 3: /*my_strchr test*/
            
                printf("\n***my_strchr*** TEST");
                
                printf("\nEnter string to search into: ");
                scanf("%s",str1);
                
                printf("Enter character to find: ");
                scanf(" %c", &c);
                
                printf("\nThe result is: %d\n",my_strchr(str1, c));
                break;
                
                
            default:    /*bad test flag*/
                printf("\nERROR: Entered number is not one of those: 1,2,3 while test is running\n");
                break;
        }
        
        printf("Should we continue? 0 to exit, 1 to continue");
        scanf("%d", &running);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

I am trying to make it work with redirection on Ubuntu 20.04 here is what I get, what I do wrong?[image: test1.in is test file but look like it doesn't run since test1.out is empty]

Comment: Does it work if you don't redirect stdout? It just ends up in an infinite loop for me, because you reach EOF then try to read more input.

Comment: If `my_strchr()` is supposed to be a replacement for `strchr()`, it should return `char *`, not `int`.

Comment: `test1.in` needs a `0` line at the end to answer the "Should we continue?" question. Otherwise it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: When I add that, change all the `my_` functions to the standard functions, and change `%d` to `%p` for `strchr()`, I get the expected output.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: It works fine without redirection, and test1 has zero line in the end

Comment: it works if I cat input file and then pipeline it

Comment: I posted an answer to your previous question, but see no reaction.